# Validation of reset password link in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, reset-password

So I already know that the default Time of Validation for the password reset link is 3 days, .
from - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout

**but** what happen if i send 3-4 mails for reset password,**i use only one of them** - what about the another links ?
as i say i sent 3-4 mails so i have 3-4 links.

If I used one link will the rest of the links no longer be valid?
someone know how its work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great article on how the reset password mechanism works: https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2016/04/07/djangos-reset-password-mechanism/

As the token consists of:

- user ID
- password
- time of last login
- current date

any previously sent link becomes invalid if the user will change the password or remember the credentials and logs in.

Comment: thanks! 
Another question, if I sent 3-4 emails again to reset my password, but used the first link I received, will the new links still be valid?

Comment: All sent links are valid as long as no parameter for the token has changed and `PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT` did not timed out. If you change the password or log in (with a link from any sent mail), all others links in the mails become automatically invalid as the password hash or last login time has changed.